# When I get my Australian visa points from ASC and SkillSelect will I get same points upon submitting my application to Immi?

Tags: working-visas, immigration, australia, paperwork

I have applied for Australian visa 189 first assessing agency is ACS (Australian Computer Society) which assessed me as suitable for migration

[image]

Then I have submitted all the paperwork (IELTS, ACS result) to SkillSelect and again I got positive response

[image]

**Will after paying application fee** (family of 4 = 7920 AUD or ~6000 USD) **I can be certain to get same points in my application?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No apparently it does not matter as agencies work separately and points that you are given by ACS and SkillSelect might greatly differ (you are likely to get less) from those you will get from Immi.gov.au by supplying same exact documents.

[image]

Hope this saves you some money and time....

Comment: Did you study in Australia? The ACS assessment only showed 10 months of work, could you not get the other experience validated?

Comment: @mkennedy Hi, it's only first page of the document you can see my points  in SkillSelect...

Answer (score 3):

On the face of it, your self-assessment of your points seems wrong to me based on what you have posted.

For example, you have given yourself 5 points for having a post graduate [Specialist Education Qualification](https://www.acacia-au.com/specialist-education-qualification-points.php) - that is a Masters by research or a PhD in one of the nominated areas (Computer Science is one). ACS have equated your qualifications to a Bachelors degree - this doesn't cut it.

You have also claimed 5 points for the [Australian Study](https://www.acacia-au.com/study-in-australia.php) requirement. *Have* you actually studied for 2 years **in** Australia?

On the other hand, assuming you have certified experience of between 3 and 5 years from ACS (I can only see 11 months in the letter but there may be more that you didn't post) you should have got 5 points for that.

You *may* be entitled to 55 points but probably not more than that.

Comment: Dale no one self assesses the points they are given by SkillSelect...

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius Skillselect is a purely automatic Q&A site where **you** answer the questions it poses about your qualifications. See https://youtu.be/tp2wYZ64ch8 at about the 4 minute mark, the user is clearly self-assessing their qualification and choosing from a drop down list. Skillselect also has some **big** disclaimers and limitations of liability clauses in its terms of service which you explicitly agreed to.

Comment: Dale when did you migrate?